# Split compilation among different machines

Tags: c++, compilation, linker

This is a theory question.

Let's say, I have 1000 Raspberry Pi Zero computers and I want all of them to compile a huge C++ project. I can send to each machine a source file to compile with every dependencies (headers) it needs and make this machine to compile only one single unit to produce an `obj` file. After all `obj` files are produced I need to link them. I'm not sure that I can split a linking step, for me it looks like a monolithic process but let's say I have a dedicated powerful single machine to do it.

So the question - will it work in theory? Will my project be compiled 1000 times faster? Is the linking process is heavy? How many time does it take comparing to preprocessor/compilation step?

Comment: We do this (while not with Raspberry Pi, but with full-featured computers) and have a good speedup of compilation whenever a huge codebase needs to be rebuild. Not 1000x though, but we don't use that many nodes. Moreover, while we use some home-build system, I can't believe no standard build system with such support exists.

Comment: Yes, they exist. We're using IncrediBuild, but licenses are costly and actually, as I mentioned before, my question is more theoretical than practical.

Answer (score 2):

You can use tools such as [distcc](https://github.com/distcc/distcc) to distribute compilation across many computers.  How much speedup you get will depend on your particular project (such as size and complexity of source files, speed of compilation computers, network latency etc).  You could make a small scale test and do measurements.

As you say, linking is often a monolithic process and can be a bottleneck in a large project.  An alternative is to split your project into several shared libraries.  Then you don't need a big link step each time you make a small change, but starting the executable may be slower since some linking must be performed at runtime.

If you make changes to several parts of the projects these libraries can be built and linked in parallel.

How much time spent in compilation vs. linking depends on your project.

Comment: Yes, I saw distcc project but I was suspicious about it since last update to the source was done 2 years ago and I'm not sure it will work with modern compilers, but maybe I'm wrong.